# How to use one-one and one -many relationships together in spring data jpa for mysql database

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am working for Resource management. In this module we will have below tables

### **requirement**

### reqId

### no_of_postions

### job_title

### req_recieved_time

### requirement_status

### experience

### skill

### location

### **resource**

### resId

### name

### experience

### skill

### location

### status

### available

### reqId(fk)

Requirement or Resource can be created independently.We have Matching screen where user can map the Resources which are matching to the Requirement (matching criteria will be skill and experience from both tables). Once user selects and save the Requirement, the status of the Resource should change. Each Resource is having statuses `[Available, Shortlisted, In_progress, Background_Verification, On boarded, Rejected]`. User can change the status of the Resource-based on the process. If one Resource is rejected then it should be available for the other Requirements. For creating the reports for one requirement how many resources are shortlisted, how many resources are onboard and how many resources are rejected we should maintain each requirement and resource status.

Then the data should be like this

```
req_res_status
---------------

resId     resId   status         updatedDate       comment

1          1      shortlisted     18/12/19         candidate shortlisted
1          1      Inprogress      19/12/19         Done with one F2F 
1          1      Rejected        20/12/19         Rejected in second round - F2F
1          2      shortlisted     18/12/19         candidate shortlisted
1          2      Inprogress      19/12/19         Done with one F2F 
1          2      BGV_check       20/12/19         Background verification In progress
1          2      onboarded       01/01/20         Onboarded 
2          1      shortlisted     20/12/19         candidate shortlisted
2          1      Inprogress      21/12/19         Done with one F2F 
2          1      BGV_check       22/12/19         Background verification In progress
2          1      onboarded       01/01/20         Onboarded
```

One requirement can have multiple resources, One resource can be associate to one requirement

How to achieve this using spring data JPA and how to maintain the relationships.

I have tried this way

### Resource.java

```
@Entity
public class Resource implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="res_id")
private int resourceId;

private String location;

private String name;

@Column(name="position")
private String jobTitle;

@Column(name="skills")
private String skill;

private String availability;

private String status;

private Integer experience;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Requirement
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="req_fk")
private Requirement requirement;

// Setters & Getters

}
```

### Resource.java

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Requirement.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Requirement r")
public class Requirement implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="req_id")
private String reqNumber;

@Column(name="acknowledge_status")
private String acknowledgeStatus;

@Column(name="acknowledge_time")
private String acknowledgeTime;

private int experience;

@Column(name="no_position")
private int noPositions;

@Column(name="req_recieved_time")
private String reqRecievedTime;

@Column(name="req_skills")
private String skill;

@Column(name="job_title")
private String position;

private String location;
@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Resource
@OneToMany(mappedBy="requirement")
private List<Resource> resources;

// setters & getters

}
```

Comment: is those are all in one table

Comment: Now data is in Requirement, Resource tables. we should generate req_res_status table using annotations in spring data jpa which I am not understanding how to use

Comment: i still not understand how many table you have what you trying do here

Comment: I have two tables 1.Requirement, 2. Resource. when we change status of a resource against Requirement  a new record should get insert into res_req_status table(This is not yet created). I should create res_req_status table  using spring data JPA relationships.

Comment: The relationship between Requirement and Resource is OneToMany, where as  relationship between Resource and Requirement is OneToOne.I want to create third table called res_req_status table(which will have following columns reqId,resId,status,comment,updatedDate) to maintain the status of each requirement and resource.

Comment: so you looking for sql query or java code

Comment: I required Java code. Please help me

Comment: can you share proper code

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Resource implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="res_id")
private int resourceId;

private String location;

private String name;

@Column(name="position")
private String jobTitle;

@Column(name="skills")
private String skill;

private String availability;

private String status;

private Integer experience;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Requirement

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "req_fk")
private Requirement requirement;

// Setters & Getters

}





@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Requirement.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Requirement r")
public class Requirement implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="req_id")
private String reqNumber;

@Column(name="acknowledge_status")
private String acknowledgeStatus;

@Column(name="acknowledge_time")
private String acknowledgeTime;

private int experience;

@Column(name="no_position")
private int noPositions;

@Column(name="req_recieved_time")
private String reqRecievedTime;

@Column(name="req_skills")
private String skill;

@Column(name="job_title")
private String position;

private String location;
@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Resource

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requirement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Resource> resources;

// setters & getters

}
```

Comment: Hi Harkesh Kumar, thabk you for your answer. When we update the status data should  updated in Resource table and Res_Req_Status table. should we manually update the two tables? How do we achieve it?

Comment: yes you can update no issue but you have you manage transaction like if one fails then what happened

Comment: Yeah that is where I am thinking to avoid manual updation. I am not understanding how to do this.

Comment: Will @Embedded and Embeddable will solve my problem? I am very new to spring Data JPA. Please suggest.

Comment: @Anusha its depend on what you trying to do